# Converting an OpenGL application to make it work on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl

I am trying to convert an openGL application to make it work for iPhone.
I am almost finished with everything. but got nothing & stuck up with this part. Can anyone tell me is everything ok with the following converted part.

```
for(int y=0;y<wet->h-1;y++)
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,tex);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,col);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,vert);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &tex[i+wet->w]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &col[i+wet->w]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, wet->w, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &vert[i+wet->w]);
}
```

in place of:

```
for(int y=0;y<wet->h-1;y++)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for(int x=0;x<wet->w;x++)
    {
        glArrayElement(i);
        glArrayElement(i+wet->w);
        i++;
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be useful if you say what problem you're seeing.

You seem to not be incrementing `i` in the new loop. How about a little `i += wet->w`, or using `y * wet->w` instead of `i`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have incremented i,but not shown here..the problem is its not showing anything except the black screen. is this the right way of conversion?